# FCM push notifications with Parse Server

Tags: android, push-notification, parse-server

This is complicated but I'll try to be as concise as possible. I am using FCM to send push notifications to Android devices. My backend is parse server. I can successfully send pushes from the FCM console to the device. And when I send pushes from parse to https://mybackend/parse/push, it says {"result": "true" } as the response. I have checked the server logs, and it (predictably) says all http post requests to /parse/push were 200 success.

However when sending from parse (using curl or the parse push console), the pushes do NOT show up in FCM console. There is some issue between parse server and FCM then.

In my index.js, I have:

```
push: {
  android: {
    senderId: "XXXXX",
    apiKey: "YYYYYY"
   }
}
```

I have the keys, and done everything according to here: http://parseplatform.org/docs/parse-server/guide/#push-notifications

what else am I missing? Why can't I get this to actually appear on the device? Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Setting up a Parse Server for an Android app, I remember having to double check this to get it right.  The key for me was this: when I logged into Firebase console and selected the app I was working on, and clicked on the gear [or cog or whatever] and then Project Settings, I had to make sure to click on the Cloud Messaging tab and grab the Legacy server key [under project credentials] NOT the web api key that appears on the General tab.  Also the sender ID that you want to use appears on that page.

I'm not sure when they will deprecate the Legacy server key, you might try the Server key instead, but definitely make sure you get the info off of the Cloud Messaging tab.

I don't know why FCM (and APNs) don't send a different message when the key (or cert) is not set up right [that would be more developer-friendly at least] and instead just send a 200 but my guess is that they evaluate the key [or cert] after receiving the intended notification and sending a response.

Comment: I tried the server legacy key, but am still experiencing the same problem unfortunately. thanks for the advice though.

Comment: Dude you have no idea how much time you just saved me. I was 7+ hours into a miserable night and you just SAVED ME. For those of you trying to add Parse Server + Android Push Notifications you NEED TO USE THE LEGACY SERVER KEY as specified by Pacificpelican above. Seriously thank you!!!!!!! can't thank you enough!! I can't believe this doesn't have any up-votes... wow.